# Approximation for metric TSP: Worst case using nearest neighbor heuristic?

Tags: tsp, heuristics

I'm looking at different heuristics that approximate solutions for a metric Traveling Salesman Problem. I was wondering if there is a worst case ratio of tours calculated by the nearest neighbor heuristic to the optimal tour.

Apparently, the Minimum Spanning Tree heuristic is a 2-approximation for metric TSPs meaning that it will only find tours that - in the worst case - are twice as long as the optimal tour. Is there some factor like this for the nearest neighbor heuristic for metric TSPs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the NN heuristic does not have constant factor for metric TSP.

Rosenkrantz, Stearns, and Lewis proved in [An Analysis of Several Heuristics for the Traveling Salesman Problem. SIAM J. Comput. 6(3): 563-581 (1977)](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0206041) that the worst case ratio of the tour obtained by the nearest neighbor method is bounded above by a logarithmic function of the number of nodes.